# unablet to connecto to sql server express database. its used by another process person

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am using asp.net with vb.net version 4.0,Sql Server Express Edition 2008
i have a database named 'database' in App_Data. I am using WCF service to connect to database and fetch the login credentials from the database table and it is giving me error. Even if use in default.aspx. it gives the same error.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Unable to open the physical file "c:\Documents and Settings\Sahil\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\TestSite\App_Data\Database.mdf". Operating system error 32: "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)".
Cannot attach the file 'c:\Documents and Settings\Sahil\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\TestSite\App_Data\Database.mdf' as database 'database'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

at login.checkLogin(String username, String pass, String role)

Here is the connection string in web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\Documents and Settings\Sahil\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\TestSite\App_Data\Database.mdf;Database=database;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True "/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

and the code in WCFservice vb code file is as

```
dim errorstring as string =""
Dim reader as SqlDataReader
Dim connection As New SqlConnection
connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connection").ConnectionString
Dim command As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        command.Connection = connection
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim user As String = username
        Dim passwd As String = pass
        Dim LoginRole = role
 command.CommandText = "select [username],[password] from login where username =@user and role=@role"
 command.Parameters.Add("@user", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user
 command.Parameters.Add("@role", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = role
command.connection = connection
try
connection.open()
reader = command.executereader
catch(Exception ex)
errorstring =ex.toString()
finally
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in your connection string.  Try this connection string instead...

```
"SERVER=[yourmachinename]\SQLEXPRESS;Database=[yourdatabasename];Trusted_Connection=True"
```

You're trying to connect directly to the database file, and SQL Server is using it.

Comment: I followed your connection string as it gives this

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "database" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'MANCHANDA\Sahil'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

Comment: Is SQL Server set to allow Windows Authentication?

Comment: Matin's question is good.  Also, if you are setup for SQL, is your Windows user mapped to a SQL login?

Comment: Yes, Sql Server is allowed to windows authentication.

Comment: And have you mapped the MANCHANDA\Sahil Windows account to a SQL login and given that login the appropriate access?